# How to Use OnActivityResult() method for ProgressBar's setMax() method

Tags: android, progress-bar

1. I have a progress bar simply designed and placed in MainActivity.
2. I have second activity to set max value of ProgressBar

My question is; how can use `public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`'s returned value for ProgressBar's setMax() method?

```
package com.example.example;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
final int request_Code = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /*I want to use value cames from onActivityResult() for setMax()
             instead of default entered value -> 100 */

         ProgressBar calorieBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress1);
         calorieBar.setMax(100);
         calorieBar.setProgress(70);



    //Go to another Activity and start
    Button newPlan  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newPlanBTN);
    newPlan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent("com.hakkikonu.dailycalorie.NEWPLAN");//new_plan activity
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
            onResume();
        }
    });

}//end of onCreate


//Sets Calorie value Comes from NewPlan.java and makes it Toast to show user
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == request_Code) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {                
                Toast.makeText(this,"Adjusted to "+data.getData().toString(), 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               // Do somethings here: get data and convert it to integer


            }            
        }
    }

 }
```

### NewPlan.Java

```
package com.hakkikonu.dailycalorie;


import com.hakkikonu.dailycalorie.R.layout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NewPlan extends Activity{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_plan);

    final TextView seekBarValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.seekBarValue);

    //Plan Button Click Listener
    final Button setPlanButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setPlanBTN);
    setPlanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

             setPlanButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

             Intent calorieVal = new Intent();

                    //---set the data to pass back---
                    calorieVal.setData(Uri.parse(
                    seekBarValue.getText().toString()));                           
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, calorieVal);

                    //---closes the activity---
                    finish(); 

        }
    });//end SetPlan Button Listener

    SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seekBar.setProgress(0);             //initial value of seekBar
    seekBar.incrementProgressBy(50);    //increment step
    seekBar.setMax(5000);               //maximum possible calory for a day.

    //seekBar Listener
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            //text view @ top of the seekBar


            progress = progress / 50;
            progress = progress * 50;
            if(progress == 0){
                seekBarValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress)+" Calorie");
            }

            else{
                seekBarValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress)+" Calories");

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            //Don't delete

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            // Don't delete

        }

    });

}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your *second* Activity puts an `int` as its extra, with a key of `"YOUR_KEY"` in its result `Intent`, just simply set the progress bar's max to that `int` extra:

```
//Sets Calorie value Comes from NewPlan.java and makes it Toast to show user
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == request_Code) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {                
                Toast.makeText(this,"Adjusted to "+data.getData().toString(), 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               ((ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress1)).setMax (data.getIntExtra ("YOUR_KEY", 0));


            }            
        }
    }
```

To make things simple (I'd say):

```
public class NewPlan extends Activity{
private int myProgress = 0;//add this line
```

Then in the changed listener:

```
 progress = progress / 50;
 progress = progress * 50;
 myProgress = progress;//add this line
```

Then to set the data, change to this:

```
Intent calorieVal = new Intent();

calorieVal.putExtra ("YOUR_KEY", myProgress);
setResult(RESULT_OK, calorieVal);

//---closes the activity---
finish();
```

Comment: I added my another activity. Maybe it can be more helpful for question. :)

Comment: @hakiko Why are you parsing a URI? Are you using some sort of provider? Why not just simply pass off the seekbar value?

Comment: sorry, i am new and , i am following some tutorials. Is there a easier way. How? Sometimes i can not understand some terms such as provider :)

Comment: i did step by step but on new_plan page after i click to button it stops!

Comment: 02-25 01:42:47.696: E/AndroidRuntime(2009): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.hakkikonu.dailycalorie/com.hakkikonu.dailycalorie.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @hakiko in `onActivityResult`, take out the Toast, since `getData()` is probably returning `null`

Comment: Ok you are right i remove Toast, now i can click button BUT on MainActivity page ProgressBar doesn't change its value. :))

Comment: @hakiko that's probably because all you've done is set the *max* value, you haven't actually changed the progress. If the ProgressBar already has a decent value, it *might* change to something more full/more empty, but it depends on what you set the new max to.

Comment: You are right, i will change progress with x.setProgress() :) THANK A LOT

Comment: You're welcome, and does that mean that the extra is being passed back to the `MainActivity` properly and that `setProgress()` works?

Comment: after i set max 3-4 times it is crashing(not app). For example if i set max value to 500, on MyActivity page firstly it is working fine. But i go to NewPlan activity again to set max value, graphic bar not show correct value. For example progress value 50, max value 100. It must fill half but it is showing me 1/4 of bar filled yellow color. There is logical error. But after i restart app. It is working fine sometimes.

Comment: Shorty this is my project folder. You can download and test it. http://speedy.sh/3ztVQ/DailyCalorie.rar

Comment: I will break the computer. How can it be possible. It is working 2-3 times then it is not working properly.

Comment: I noticed somethings. If i set max value less than current progress value it is not working

Comment: @hakiko It seems to work for me, by that I mean the bar (ProgressBar) did change up until I passed back 0, then the bar stayed empty. I suggest playing with it more, and asking a new question if you're still having problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you set resulting intent in NEWPLAN Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("myInt", 12);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);

finish();
```

And then in MainActivity you fetch that data using:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     if (requestCode == yourRequestCode && RESULT_OK) {                
         int myInt = data.getIntExtra("myInt", 0);
         // do more if you wish
     }
 }
```

Comment: So can i use myInt variable out of *onActivityResult(...)*

Comment: @hakiko Of course - the either move it to be a field of MainActivity, or use it right away -> calorieBar.setMax(myInt);

Comment: sorry, i don't understand this : *intent.putExtra("myInt", 12);*

Comment: you missed resultCode == RESULT_OK